# Apple MDM custom server for parental control app

Tags: ios, mdm, parental-control

Can I use a custom apple mdm server without Apple DEP program for ios   parental control app?

Comment: What kind of parental control app you are referring to? Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Parent app that control installed user apps and time of usage. Like [Kidtrol](https://itunes.apple.com/ua/app/kidtrol-parent-app/id1043747298?mt=8)

Comment: Hi Andriy do you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am quite late to answer this question, still for future reader here i go -

Yes you can, you will have same control in terms of allowed commands/profiles provided your iPhone/iPad is supervised using [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) .

Only major benefits of having DEP is- there is option to disallow user MDM profile removal.

Now a days, you can attach/link your old devices also with you DEP account, by using [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has started to remove from AppStore apps that use MDM for parental control.

They reject apps as voilation [AppStore guidelines - 2.5.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-completeness):

> Apps should use APIs and frameworks for their intended purposes and indicate that integration in their app description.